# Why isn't my component observable updating?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have implemented an observable to retrieve contacts in a component. How it works is I've set up an `httpService` whose pure function is making and returning an HTTP call as follows:

**httpService.ts**

```ts
getContactsHttp(params: any) {
     let headers: any = new HttpHeaders(this.authService.getHeadersClient());
     return this.httpClient.get<ContactSearch[]>('/contacts', {headers: headers, params: params});
    }
```

I then have a contact service which makes the actual calls and stores the response in an observable `contacts$`. The reason I don't do this in the component is that I will have multiple components accessing the `contacts$` observable.

**contactService.ts**

```ts
contacts$: Observable<ContactSearch[]>;
getContacts$(params: any) {
    this.contacts$ = this.httpService.getContactsHttp(params);
    this.contacts$.subscribe();    
  }
```

In my primary component I link the component `contacts$` to the `contactService` in the constructor. I then call `getContacts` on `ngOnInit`.

**component.ts**

```ts
contacts$: Observable<ContactSearch[]>;
constructor(contactService:ContactService){
  this.contacts$ = this.contactService.contacts$;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.fetch();
}
fetch() {
  let params: any = null;
  this.contactService.getContacts$(params);
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="contacts$ | async">
  Content Fetched!
</div>
```

When I load the component, it performs the fetch but `contacts$` doesn't update and the view doesn't change. I know the API call is working correctly as I have an HTTP interceptor active and can see it calling the HTTP client. So it must be how I am declaring `contacts$` in the constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The get observable has no replay behaviour, I'd guess that's the issue; have a look at this blog post I wrote for a pattern for exposing data to components: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning your `contacts$` in the `constructor` of the component, but fetch the list in `ngOnInit`, `ngOnInit` works after `constructor` so i think that's the reason why you don't see the changes, so assign `contacts$` inside `ngOnInit`, because it is better place for it then the `constructor`, and do it everywhere because it isn't suggested to do such things inside `constructor`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.fetch();
  this.contacts$ = this.contactService.contacts$;
}
```

another thing, to not send http request every time you call `getContacts$`, you can use `shareReplay` operator of `rxjs` to share the data only sending http request once

```
getContacts$(params: any) {
    this.contacts$ = this.httpService.getContactsHttp(params).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    this.contacts$.subscribe();    
}
```